# Save String from public method

Tags: java, android, string

I'm working on a school project in Android Studio and I might have a really simple (maybe stupid) question but I really don't know how to do it. So I wrote a code which generates a random eqaution everytime you press a button on the screen. The equation then shows up on the screen. Here is the code:

```
String[] operationSet = new String[]{"+", "-", "/", "*"};

public void generate(View view) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int numOfOperations = random.nextInt(2) + 1;

    List<String> operations = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfOperations; i++) {
        String operation = operationSet[random.nextInt(4)];
        operations.add(operation);
    }

    int numOfNumbers = numOfOperations + 1;
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfNumbers; i++) {
        int number = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
        numbers.add(number);
    }

    String equation = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfOperations; i++) {
        equation += numbers.get(i);
        equation += operations.get(i);
    }
    equation += numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1);

    TextView TextEquation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextEquation.setText(equation);

    String StringResultOfEquation = String.valueOf(equation);

}
```

I now want to save the String "StringResultOfEquation" public so I can use this String in the next public void or public class. 
I might just be stupid but I really don't know how to do it because when I tried to use the "StringResultOfEquation" in my next public void, it just gave me an error with unknown String.
I need to have the String in my next public void because I want to evaluate the result of the equation.

If something is unclear in my question, feel free to ask and I will try to clarify the problem.

Comment: Please follow Java naming convention.  Your variable should start with lower case, i.e. `stringResultOfEquation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared `StringResultOfEquation` as a local variable, its scope is limited to the `generate()` method.

The simpliest solution might be to make `StringResultOfEquation` an instance variable by moving its declaration outside the `generate()` method:

```
String StringResultOfEquation;

public void generate(View view) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int numOfOperations = random.nextInt(2) + 1;

    List<String> operations = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfOperations; i++) {
        String operation = operationSet[random.nextInt(4)];
        operations.add(operation);
    }

    int numOfNumbers = numOfOperations + 1;
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfNumbers; i++) {
        int number = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
        numbers.add(number);
    }

    String equation = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfOperations; i++) {
        equation += numbers.get(i);
        equation += operations.get(i);
    }
    equation += numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1);

    TextView TextEquation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TextEquation.setText(equation);

    StringResultOfEquation = String.valueOf(equation);

}
```

Also take a look at the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that declaring `String StringResultOfEquation` out of the `generate()` method, by doing this, the value assigned to **StringResultOfEquation** will be visible by other methods inside the class...

Answer (score -3):

```
String[] operationSet = new String[]{"+", "-", "/", "*"};
public static String StringResultOfEquation ;
public void generate(View view) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int numOfOperations = random.nextInt(2) + 1;

List<String> operations = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < numOfOperations; i++) {
    String operation = operationSet[random.nextInt(4)];
    operations.add(operation);
}

int numOfNumbers = numOfOperations + 1;
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < numOfNumbers; i++) {
    int number = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
    numbers.add(number);
}

String equation = "";
for (int i = 0; i < numOfOperations; i++) {
    equation += numbers.get(i);
    equation += operations.get(i);
}
equation += numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1);

TextView TextEquation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
TextEquation.setText(equation);

 StringResultOfEquation = String.valueOf(equation);
```

}

// If you want to use StringResultOfEquation variable in another class just do like this

> Take another class for e.g. Abc

```
String name=firstclassname.StringResultOfEquation;
```

Comment: Visibility does not apply to methods variables.